# Blazor Redirect Issue from Login Page to Forget Password Page

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, blazor-server-side, mudblazor, reset-password

I'm encountering an issue in my Blazor application related to navigation. I have a "Forget Password" page with the @attribute [AllowAnonymous] to allow unauthenticated users to reset their password. However, when a user clicks on the "Forget Password" link in login page, they are automatically redirected to the login page although the url is set to /forgetpassword.

Here's a simplified version of my "Forget Password" page:

```
@page "/forgetpassword"
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

<!-- Forget Password page content -->
```

I want unauthenticated users to stay on the "Forget Password" page when they click on the respective link. The issue seems to be with the automatic redirection. How can I prevent this redirection to the login page and keep the user on the "Forget Password" page?

Any insights or suggestions on how to customize the navigation behavior for this specific scenario would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a lot more information about what you're trying to do - in particular, what project type you're using. 
If you can provide a minimal reproducible example, including both the C# code and the project file, 
we're much more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: 1. I tried using NavigationManager for redirection, but it didn't work as expected.
2. Implemented a custom authentication provider to check user authentication status. I want unauthenticated users to stay on the "Forget Password" page when they click on the respective link. The issue seems to be with the automatic redirection. The MainLayout.razor page  ""<NotAuthorized>
    <LoginLayout>
        <Login />
    </LoginLayout>
</NotAuthorized>""